# Random switch bound depending on filled TextViews

Tags: java, android, random, switch-statement, bounds

I started coding some months ago and started practicing on my own app.
Six names can be entered and after that random names are matches with random tasks, which works fine if you enter all six names.

Now I want the random bound to be capped by the textViews that actually contain entered names...

```
Random r = new Random();
int Case = r.nextInt(6);

switch(Case){  
case 0: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;  


case 1: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player2");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;  

case 2: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player3");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;  

case 3: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player4");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;  

case 4: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player5");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;  

case 5: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player6");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;  

case 6: tv = findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Player7");  
    tv.setText(st);  
break;
```

I think of using something like

```
int x;
if (textView1 filled && TextView2 empty){x=0}
if else (textview1 filled && TextView2 filled && TextView3 empty) {x=1} etc.
Random r = new Random();
int Case = r.nextInt(x);
```

Comment: Is this Android?

Comment: Don't use a `Switch-Statement`. Use/pass a List to the next `Activity`.

Comment: I assumed this is `Android` from the code and added the `Android` Tag. You need to start here.->   Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking if the views are empty first and then using a counter to keep track. Then use that counter as the bound.

You can check if a Textview is empty like this:

```
TextView text= findById(R.id.textview);
Boolean isEmpty =text.getText().toString().isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

But what will happend if `if else (textview1 filled && TextView2 filled && TextView3 empty) {x=1} etc.` third field will be empty and fourt will not? Better is collect all your fields in array and iterate. If field is filled then add 1 to counter. Something like this:

```
int filledCount = 0;
TextView[] views = {TextView1, TextView2, ...};
for (TextView view : views)
{if (view.filled) filledCount++;}
```

If you use java 8 use streams. `Stream.of(TextView1,TextView2,...).filter(TextView::isFilled).count();`